# Failed to > convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type > [com.rh.app.batch.domain.A] java

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I tried to get data from table B and saved it into Class Object A

```
 A sale = repository.getSale(m, stmtDate);
```

**repository**

```
public interface repository extends JpaRepository<B, String> {
@Query(value = " SELECT ID AS id FROM B...LEFT JOIN C ... ", nativeQuery = true)
    A getSale(@Param("m") String m, @Param("date") String stmtDate);
}
```

**Class A**

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {

 private String id; 
 public String getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
  }
    .....
```

**Error**

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type
>   [com.rh.app.batch.domain.A] for value
>   '{0e89c64c-d840-45c5-9c6a-bda52fbaa7d1, 201802, 5.000, 1, 0, 0}';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to
>   type [com.rh.app.batch.domain.A]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if that is what you are looking for but, when you want to map the results of a complex query into one object, you can use the [SqlResultSetMapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html) annotation:

Assuming you have a class like.

```
public class PersonDTO {

private String name;
private Date birthDate;
//omit other attributes 

public Person(String name, Date birthDate) {
  this.name = name;
  this.birthDate = birthDate;

}
```

you decorate it as follows.

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="PersonDTOMapping",
                     classes="@ConstructorResult(
                     targetClass= PersonDTO.class,
                     columns = {@ColumnResult(name="name"),
                                @ColumnResult(name="birhDate")}))
```

and your query becomes:

```
PersonDTO person = (PersonDTO) em.createNativeQuery("select p.name, p.birthDate as date from person where p.id=1", "PersonDTOMapping").getSingleResult();
```

please let me know, if this is what you re looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was solved by adding the default constructor.
For example:

```
public Person() {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The repository will map Objects on the same repository only.  If the classes do not match you get that error.

You have **JpaRepository<B, String>**

which is a repository for a Object type B

But you are converting to an Type **Object A**.  Do it in a Repository for A and it will work(assuming you have the right columns).

Answer (score 0):

**@NamedNativeQuery** along with **@SqlResultSetMapping** is the solution to this . This is useful if you want to do some manipulation on that before sending it to REST client . I personally just used Object in place of DTO class and worked for me . This is much simpler in coding terms but not sure in terms of security & so . Make sure you are sending only required data using this . The below is the code in your case (Just replace A with Object).

```
    public interface repository extends JpaRepository<B, String> {
       @Query(value = " SELECT ID AS id FROM B...LEFT JOIN C ... ", nativeQuery = true)
       Object getSale(@Param("m") String m, @Param("date") String stmtDate);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your repository interface method returns `A.class` type object, where as your query returns `String (id)`

Try changing the query to 
`SELECT * FROM..`

Or changing the method signature like
`String getMerchantSaleTxn(...`

### Edit

For storing data from one table other, you have to do something like below

```
B b = bRepository.findByMyId(myId);
A a = b.getA();  //some method that converts B to A
aRepository.save(a);
```

bRepository method

```
@Query("select * from b where myId=:myId")
B findByMyId(myId);
```

Comment: But the repository will return others data from others table. All the data will be stored into class object A.

Comment: but that will be using different method right.. your method signature doesn't match with your query result

Comment: is class A an entity or a simple POJO/DTO?

Comment: Still your repository method return type is not matching your query return type. also edited answer demonstrating how to save records from one table to other

Comment: @EiriniGraonidou is `@Entity`

Comment: @JosAngelGeorge If I want to join three tables, then how should I write

Comment: by `join` do you mean SQL Join(do a SQL query that uses fields from all 3 tables and return the result)?? if so its just about writing the correct SQL query..  if not please describe what you mean by join??

Comment: that is very subjective and afaik not the issue reported in initial post... you can create a new question for that if you are facing any issue on SQL join. only relevant aspect is that, you should make sure that the type of data returned from the SQL (in query given in original post, its `String`) should match the corresponding method return type (in original post, the method is `getSale` and return type is `A.class`).

Comment: my query no problem. I just don't understand how to get the data from multiple tables and save to class object A